# New Azure Devops Merge Type 'Rebase and fast-forward'

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-merge

[image: New]

Two version of Azure Devops merge type is given here: 
Above is new merge type and below old one. 
Old had 'Rebase', the equivalent in new is 'Rebase and fast-forward' what is the difference? [image]

Comment: There is no difference. It's just more descriptive now.

Comment: @DanielMann Since this comment is the direct answer to the question, maybe you can consider adding it as answer with a bit more details. Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59721331/new-azure-devops-merge-type-rebase-and-fast-forward#comment105593554_59721331), regarding the newer text of "Rebase and fast-forward", there is no difference and this is a better description, especially since the next option of "Semi-linear merge" means exactly "Rebase without fast-forward".

By the way, this isn't well documented, but if you choose either of the rebase options, and also decide to uncheck the option for deleting your source branch when completing the PR, note that **if a rebase is needed, your source branch is actually re-written**. This means that after the PR is completed, at your next fetch you will see that your branch has been force updated, and will now be out of sync with your local copy.

Also, with either of the rebase options, if a rebase occurred, when you go to delete your local branch, you will need to use a capital "D" instead of a lowercase "d":

`git branch -D your-source-branch-that-was-rebased-then-merged`

Note these caveats only apply if a rebase was necessary. If you are in the habit of rebasing your branch onto the target shortly before completing your PR, then the rebase option probably won't have any effect most of the time.

Comment: What would be the equivalent at the command line to the Rebase and Fast Forward option?

Comment: @cognophile if you are PR'ing `feature` into `main`, the AzDO repo would do this: `git switch feature`, then `git rebase main`, then `git switch main`, then `git merge --ff-only feature`. For semi-linear merge it uses `--no-ff` instead of `--ff-only`. Note the `--ff-only` may not actually be necessary since merge will fast-forward by default, and the AzDO server might have an exclusive lock behind the scenes- if it does the `--ff-only` would be redundant.